# rmarkdown: bold inside \tabular{}

Tags: text, formatting, r-markdown

I have

````
---
title: ""
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
```

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll}
***Why***  & one\\  
*does* & two\\
**this happen** & three \\ 
  \end{tabular}
````

However Why does this happen appear in normal font and not italics/bold.

[image]

How can I change this?

Comment: This helps: ```{\bf Text}```

Comment: \textbf{This did the job}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did the job

````
---
title: ""
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
```

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll}
  \textbf{Why}  & one\\  
  \textbf{does} & two\\
  \textbf{This happen} & three \\ 
    \end{tabular}
````

[image]